# how do I find favorite questions

Tags: support

I marked a question as "favorite" using the star icon on the left. I now want to go back to it but can't work out how to list my favorite questions. Can't find anything in help either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the *Activity* tab on your profile—

[image: Activity tab]

— you will see a *favorites* link in the list of subtabs about halfway down the page:

[image: Subtabs]

(This does seem a little clumsy, and perhaps this is why I have never used the favorite questions feature. Favorite tags, in contrast, are accessible directly from the sidebar.)

Comment: Thanks - got it. A bit hidden away!